# How does libcxx std::counting_semaphore implement "Strongly happens before" for release / acquire?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, memory-barriers, stdatomic

libc++ `std::counting_semaphore` uses atomic increment with `memory_order_release` in [`release` method](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/libcxx/include/semaphore#L88):

```
    void release(ptrdiff_t __update = 1)
    {
        if(0 < __a.fetch_add(__update, memory_order_release))
            ;
        else if(__update > 1)
            __a.notify_all();
        else
            __a.notify_one();
    }
```

And compare exchange with `memory_order_acquire` successful memory order in [`acquire` method](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/libcxx/include/semaphore#L100):

```
    void acquire()
    {
        auto const __test_fn = [=]() -> bool {
            auto __old = __a.load(memory_order_relaxed);
            return (__old != 0) && __a.compare_exchange_strong(__old, __old - 1, memory_order_acquire, memory_order_relaxed);
        };
        __cxx_atomic_wait(&__a.__a_, __test_fn);
    }
```

Obvious choice to make acquire synchronized with release.

---

However, C++20 draft [says](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.sema.cnt#10):

> ```
> void release(ptrdiff_t update = 1);
> ```
>
> ...
>
> *Synchronization:* Strongly happens before invocations of try_­acquire that observe the result of the effects.

*Strongly happens before* is somewhat more than *synchronizes with*, C++20 draft [says](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.races#12):

> An evaluation A strongly happens before an evaluation D if, either
>
> - (12.1) A is sequenced before D, or
> - (12.2) A synchronizes with D, and both A and D are sequentially consistent atomic operations ([atomics.order]), or
> - (12.3) there are evaluations B and C such that A is sequenced before B, B simply happens before C, and C is sequenced before D, or
> - (12.4) there is an evaluation B such that A strongly happens before B, and B strongly happens before D.

I guess 12.2 would have been the best fit here, where A is `fetch_add`, D is `compare_exchange_strong`. **But in addition to being synchronized with, they should have been seq_cst!**

Trying 12.3 doesn't seem to help either. We call `fetch_add` B, and `compare_exchange_strong` C. Fine, but where are A and D then?

So how does it work (according to the C++20 Standard draft)?

---

The same applies to `std::latch` and `std::barrier`.

I picked one (`std::semaphore`) to refer easily specific paragraphs and lines.

Comment: You are looking at an implementation written for a specific compiler, g++. It doesn't have to be portable, it just has to work with g++. g++ may provide stronger guarantees than the standard.

Comment: I am looking at libc++, which has to work with Clang.  Anyway, it still doesn't answer the question, unless the _stronger guarantee_ is pointed at. (I think that the implementation is correct and generic, and does not need stronger guarantees; the problem is with my understamding, or (less likely) with Standard wording)

Comment: Oh sorry my bad. Apparently I can't read. Anyway it is implemented in terms of compare_exchange_strong which is in turn implemented with a gcc(-like) builtin. I don't know what guarantees it provides.

Comment: Actually I suspect that all the magic is due to notify_all/wait interaction.

Comment: If count never reaches zero, there's no wait/notify. Ditto for barrier, which might never lock: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63120083/2945027

Comment: Now I'm not even sure what the standard even means by "invocations of try_­acquire that observe the result of the effects". The counter was 5, `release` incremented it, `try_acquire` decremented it. It makes little sense to say that `release` happened or not happened before `acquire`, since the difference is unobservable. I give up and admit my cluelessness,

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0668r5.html explains the reason behind the strong/simply change  - it's to resolve an issue when you mix seq_cst and weaker ordering on the same location. Since this atomic is only accessed by the implementation, it is free to use the weaker ordering only under as-if.